# iOS: too many initWithDelegate messages and compiler warnings

Tags: iphone, ios, delegation

One of my view controllers relies on several classes that each have an initWithDelegate: method. The view controller is the delegate in all cases. I get compiler warnings on all calls to

```
[[ONE_OF_FOUR_CLASSES] alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
```

except for the first (who's header file is loaded first).

All the others give an "incompatible pointer types assigning to xx from yy" warning. yy is always that first of the 4 classes.

Everything runs fine, however. So how do I suppress these warnings? Is this an LLVM bug?

Comment: You should ignore all the answers that use casts after alloc. This is clearly the wrong thing to do, even though I can't tell you the exact reason for your warnings.

Comment: I'm afraid that the id parameter returned from the call to +alloc is the exact reason for the compiler warning, hence why the cast is needed.

Comment: Thanks Mike! My init methods were not returning id's but whatever class they were found on in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds as if the types doesn't match or are not known to the compiler. Don't forget to add the signatures of your `init`-methods to your .h files and import them. Check that they return an `id` and that `delegate` is of type `id` as well (at least that's what you want most of the time).

Feel free to edit your question to include more code if this doesn't clear things up.

Comment: Nope, I got it now.. I wasn't returning id's from the init methods but rather instances of whatever class the init method was in..

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to suppress the warning was to do the following:

`[(ONE_OF_FOUR_CLASSES *)[ONE_OF_FOUR_CLASSES alloc] initWithDelegate:self];`

This cast enables the compiler to realise the return value of the +(id)alloc call is not 'id' but is actually your ONE_OF_FOUR_CLASSES.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `alloc` returns `id`, so the compiler doesn't know that [CLASS_1 alloc] returns an object of type CLASS_1. It usually infers the type right and doesn't add the warning, but sometimes it doesn't. My usual solution is a cast. Ugly, but it works.

```
[(CLASS_1*)[CLASS_1 alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Sorry after reading the other answers I've had to select Eiko's.. my initWithDelegate methods weren't returning id's but the actual class the method was found in!